# Wait for a command to finish before executing the next line

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard, paste, timing

When the following runs with the clipboard containing some data, `Clipboard := x` executes before the last `send ^v` has finished.

```
#!.::
count = 400
x := ClipboardAll
Clipboard := "2019 sales have reached quota; prep audit trail and incentive program"
Loop % count - 1
send ^v{Enter}
send ^v
Clipboard := x
```

`Sleep` isn’t an elegant solution since the sleep time would be assumed and may not be enough for large values of `count`. `Clipboard := x` would prematurely execute.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Clipwait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ClipWait.htm) command

> **ClipWait**
>   Waits until the clipboard contains data.